# array required, but ArrayList<String> found

Tags: java

I have a ruby backround and im new to java i wrote a basic programm but somehow i get a error i cant fix! My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Music {

    private ArrayList<String> files;


    public static void main(String args[]){

        Music a = new Music();
        a.addFile("Chasen Paper");
        a.addFile("Mama");
        a.addFile("Hell Yes");
        a.removeFile("Hell Yes");
    }
    public Music(){
      files = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addFile(String filename){
        files.add(filename);
    }

    public void returnFiles(){
        for(int i = 0; files.size() <= i; i++){
            System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files[i]);
        }

    }

    public void removeFile(String filename){
        System.out.println("Vorher gab es " + files.size() + " Dateien");
        files.remove(filename);
        System.out.println("Jetzt gibt es " + files.size() + " Dateien");
    }
}
```

When i try to compile it i get somehow this error: What did i wrong? Thanks!

```
Music.java:26: error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found
            System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files[i]);
```

Comment: How do you get an element at index `i` from an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method to get the element at a particular index from an `ArrayList`. You can't use `[]` to get the element at a particular index, in an arraylist. Its possible only for arrays and your `files` is not an array, but an ArrayList.

```
System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files.get(i));
```

Also, the condition in your `for` loop is a bit off. `files.size() <= i` is `false`, and therefore, it doesn't enter the `for` loop at all.

Change it to something like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.size() ; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the arraylist like an array you have to use the method get(index) in order to get the i th element.

```
   public void returnFiles(){
        for(int i = 0;i< files.size() ; i++){
            System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files.get(i));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you rolling this back over and over again?

Comment: @BoltClock it was because there were many revisions and i got confused sorry about that..

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
for(int i = 0; files.size() <= i; i++){
    System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files[i]);
}
```

As

```
for(String i:files){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you need index

```
int index = 0;
for(String i:files){
        System.out.println((index++) + ".Ist: " +i);
    }
```

Comment: If you need the index, you should not be using a for-each loop and instead use a correct version of the original loop, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

files[i] is used for arrays. While working with lists you need to use indexing. Try files.get(i)

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem is in this method

```
public void returnFiles(){
        for(int i = 0; files.size() <= i; i++){
            System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files[i]);
        }

 }
```

Precisely, on the

```
files[i]
```

You are trying to access your ArrayList instance variable as if it were a an Array. Just change that for

```
files.get(i)
```

You have to use the method `get(int index)` from the ArrayList<> class.

Answer (score 0):

files is an `ArrayList` and not an `Array` instead of doing `files[i]` you must do this-

```
        for(int i = 0; files.size() <= i; i++){
            System.out.println( i + ". Ist: " + files.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use files.get(i) as your are using ArrayList and not Array.
When you are using array at that time you will require its index location to fetch values from it.ArrayList provides get(i) method to fetch values from init.